# How to delete multiple rows with checkbox in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sql-delete

This is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(IEnumerable<int> idDelete)
{
    foreach(var item in idDelete)
    {
        var delete = db.ExamPolicies.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ExamPolicyID == item);
        db.ExamPolicies.Attach(delete);
        db.ExamPolicies.Remove(delete);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Display");
}
```

And this is my input

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "ExamPolicy", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="btn-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete All" />
    </div>
}
```

this is my checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="@item.ExamPolicyID" name="ExamPolicyIDs"/>
```

I dont know why my code is wrong? Please, help me

Comment: Where are you checkboxes within the `<form>` tags? And your checkboxes have `name="ExamPolicyIDs"` so the POST method needs to be `public ActionResult Delete(IEnumerable<int> ExamPolicyIDs)`

Comment: I fixed Delete method. checkboxes is in Html.BeginForm. 
But it still erorr in foreach(var item in ExamPolicyIDs)

Comment: What error? (we are not psychic)

Answer (score 0):

Change your Delete action like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(IEnumerable<int> ExamPolicyIDs)
{
    foreach (var item in ExamPolicyIDs)
    {
        var delete = db.ExamPolicies.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ExamPolicyID == item);
        if (delete != null)
        {
            db.ExamPolicies.Remove(delete);
        }
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Display");
}
```